# django-piston generated documentation for several handlers

Tags: python, django, django-piston

I'm having a problem regarding the automagic documentation generated in django-pyston. Right now I have this and works:

```
from piston.handler import BaseHandler
from piston.doc import generate_doc

class FirstHandler(BaseHandler): 
...

doc = generated_doc(FirstHandler)
```

And is working fine. The problem is when I add a SecondHandler, I don't know how I should add it to the doc variable.

Piston own documentation isn't that well, don't mentioning [anything about several handlers](https://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/wiki/Documentation#!generating-documentation). Seeing in the code itself ([doc.py](https://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/src/c4b2d21db51a/piston/doc.py)) seems to be that using documentation_view should propagate every handler automatically, but it doesn't (or I'm doing it wrong):

```
from piston.doc import documentation_view

...

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^/doc$', documentation_view),
...
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to have the line

```
doc = generated_doc(FirstHandler)
```

within the module containing the Handlers. It's just a smaple from the poor documentation.
The documentation view fetches all handlers automatically and then generated the documentation. Remove the line and it should work.